# Web Scraping does not give the desired results

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape some data from a website and the HTML code would look like as follows.

```
<div class="field-wrapper field field-node--field-test-synonyms field-name-field-test-synonyms field-type-string field-label-inline clearfix">
      <div class="field-label">Also Known As</div>
    <div class="field-items">
          <div class="field-item">KOH Prep</div>
          <div class="field-item">Fungal Smear, Culture, Antigen and Antibody Tests</div>
          <div class="field-item">Mycology Tests</div>
          <div class="field-item">Fungal Molecular Tests</div>
          <div class="field-item">Potassium Hydroxide Preparation</div>
          <div class="field-item">Calcofluor White Stain</div>
      </div>
</div>
```

The output what I want to get is `OH Prep, Fungal Smear, Culture, Antigen and Antibody Tests, Mycology Tests,  Fungal Molecular Tests...`

But I don't get any output. My code us as follows.

```
def get_similar_names(sub_url):
    response = requests.get(sub_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    if(soup.find('div', class_='field-label')!= None):
        other_names = [
            tag.next.next.get_text(strip=True, separator='|').split('|')
            for tag in soup.find('div', class_='field-label')
        ]
        return (other_names[0])
    else:
        return None
```

The actual link for the web page is [this](https://labtestsonline.org/tests/fungal-tests)

Comment: Those items are of class `field-item` not `field-label`

Comment: Besides that, unclear why you need to use `tag.next.next.get_text` when the text is directly inside those found div tags. Also, you don't need to use a list comprehension if you're only going to return the first element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different approaches to get the names.

#1 - Get all `names` joined as a `string` as you expected output:

```
soup.select_one('div.field-items').get_text(',',strip=True)

Output -> KOH Prep,Fungal Smear, Culture, Antigen and Antibody Tests,Mycology Tests,Fungal Molecular Tests,Potassium Hydroxide Preparation,Calcofluor White Stain
```

#2 - Get all `names`as a `list`:

```
[name.get_text() for name in soup.select('div.field-items > div')]

Output -> ['KOH Prep','Fungal Smear, Culture, Antigen and Antibody Tests','Mycology Tests','Fungal Molecular Tests','Potassium Hydroxide Preparation','Calcofluor White Stain']
```

#3 _ Get only the first `name` as in your code:

```
soup.select_one('div.field-items > div').get_text()

Output -> KOH Prep
```

**Example**

```
def get_similar_names(sub_url):
    response = requests.get(sub_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    other_names = soup.select_one('div.field-items').get_text(',',strip=True)

    return other_names
```

**Output**

```
KOH Prep,Fungal Smear, Culture, Antigen and Antibody Tests,Mycology Tests,Fungal Molecular Tests,Potassium Hydroxide Preparation,Calcofluor White Stain
```

Answer (score 1):

When I examined the core of your scraping code as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_content='''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="field-wrapper field field-node--field-test-synonyms field-name-field-test-synonyms field-type-string field-label-inline clearfix">
      <div class="field-label">Also Known As</div>
    <div class="field-items">
          <div class="field-item">KOH Prep</div>
          <div class="field-item">Fungal Smear, Culture, Antigen and Antibody Tests</div>
          <div class="field-item">Mycology Tests</div>
          <div class="field-item">Fungal Molecular Tests</div>
          <div class="field-item">Potassium Hydroxide Preparation</div>
          <div class="field-item">Calcofluor White Stain</div>
      </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')
if(soup.find('div', class_='field-label')!= None):
     other_names = [
       tag.next.next.get_text(strip=True, separator='|').split('|')
       for tag in soup.find('div', class_='field-label')
     ]
     print (other_names)
```

The content of `other_names` is:

```
[['KOH Prep', 'Fungal Smear, Culture, Antigen and Antibody Tests', 'Mycology Tests', 'Fungal Molecular Tests', 'Potassium Hydroxide Preparation', 'Calcofluor White Stain']]
```

That match with your target results.

As your code give the target result, therefore, you may have a problem elsewhere, in the sent `sub_url` for example.